# not able to match code between two comments, mutiple times

Tags: java, regex

I want to get content between two comments in some file.

like a file x

```
#user code
alert("");
alert("");
#user code


{
 ===
====
}

#user code
alert("as");
alert("as");
#user code
```

i am using this regex pattern to match

```
final Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("//#User code\r?\n(.*)\r?\n//#User code" ,    Pattern.DOTALL);
```

but its matching from first #user code to end of the file.

pls help.

Comment: You may also want to use case insensitive flag `(?i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix is to use `.*?` instead of just `.*`. The `?` changes the `*` into a *non-greedy* repetition, which will match up until the nearest `#user code`, instead of the furthest.